# How to create style of html elements while php codes are embedded in it?

Tags: php, html, css

I have this php file where I want to retrieve data from database and show in a tabular format.

```
<html>

 <head>

  <title>Admin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adminPanel.css"/>

 </head>

 <body>

  <div class="header">

   <h1>Admin</h1>

  </div>

  <div class="center">

   <?php 

    include "db_connection.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM appointments;";

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    If(mysqli_query($db,$sql) == TRUE){

   ?>

      <table>

         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th>License</th>
         <th>Engine</th>
         <th>Appointment Date</th>
         <th>Preferred Mechanic</th>      

    <?php 

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    ?>

      <td><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td></br>  
      <td><?php echo $row['Address'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Phone'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Car_license_No'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Car_Engine_No'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Date'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Mechanic'];?></td>

    <?php  

     }

    ?>

     </table>

    <?php    

    }

    ?>

  </div>  

  <div class="footer">

   <p id="lastMod">
    <script language="Javascript">
     document.write("Last modified on " + document.lastModified + " ");
    </script>
   </p>

  </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

But the problem is I can`t change the style of data showing in the table. The .footer, .center, .header these are showing up with the perfect style. But styles of html elements that are written within the php blocks are not working, such as , , .

Here is my style sheet

```
.header{
    background-color: black;
    color: DC143C;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: "Impact"
}

.center{
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.footer{
    background-color: black;
    font-family: "Impact";
    color: DC143C;
    margin-top: 82px;
    height: 95px;
}

th, td{
    color: white;
}

#lastMod{
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Searched a lot but havn`t found any relevant answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, that html table you define by means of php does not contain any of the class names you use in the css style rules. So why do you expect them to get applied?

Comment: add class in your table like `class="mytable"` and  style it by pointing with parent such `.mytable th { color:#fff; }`

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the classes to cells then you could style it.

```
      <td class="name"><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td></br>  
...
      <td class="mechanic"><?php echo $row['Mechanic'];?></td>

<style>
td.name {
   background-color: #0f0;
}
....
td.mechanic {
   background-color: #f00;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't added any class in your php you should add class in your table like

`<table class="mytable">`

and style it by pointing with parent such as

`<style>
 .mytable th { color:#fff; }
 </style>`